# Refresh typed dataset (xsd) after changing column property

Tags: sql, .net, ado.net, visual-studio-2013, dataset

I have strongly typed dataset object in my VS project. I changed the "auto-increment" to Yes on one of the columns in database table. Is there a way to reflect that change in my xsd, without manually changing the property in VS IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Data Sources window, right click in the pane and select Refresh.

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot about Data source window